# What is "WMD" an acronym for?

Tags: discussion, editor

#### Original Question

Meta Stack Overflow has a [wmd](/questions/tagged/wmd) tag: What does it stand for? Its [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/wmd/info) does not contain any information (yet). I imagine that "M" stands for "Markdown", but beyond that I'm drawing a blank.

#### Update

Since I asked this question, the [wmd](/questions/tagged/wmd) [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/wmd/info) has been updated with some basic information. Feel free to expand upon it as you see fit.

Comment: I guess I should interpret downvotes in this case as the equivalent of saying *"Who cares"*?  :p

Comment: ...or that it's the fifth link down when you Google "WMD" (i.e. kinda easy to find on your own).

Comment: Ah, good point. I just assumed that it was a Stack Overflow-specific thing, but you know what happens when you assume...

Comment: Technically, it's not an acronym. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31864/how-can-i-tell-when-an-abbreviation-is-an-acronym

Comment: @Al: Really? Even according to [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/difference-between-an-acronym-and-abbreviation/3759#3759)?

Comment: @Chris: The accepted answer is wrong. Note the comments.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym_and_initialism has more, noting that to most people it's come to mean the same as abbreviation.

Comment: Weapon of Markup Destruction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It stands for **W**YSIWYM **M**ark**d**own. It's usually used in form of "WMD Editor" which in turn stands for [WYSIWYM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM) [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) Editor which in turn stands for What You See Is What You Mean Markdown Editor.

#### Related:

- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/
- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/markdown-one-year-later/